# span height inside link is truncated

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add some background image inside span elements with some vertical offset (`background-position-y: 2px;`)

But, even if the link element is `50px` height, the `img` in span element is vertically truncated.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
a span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-position-y: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 13px;
}
a .open {
  background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_161877bracketleft.gif');
}
a .close {
  background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_762032bracketright.gif');
}
```

```html
<p>
  some text <a href="#"><span class="open"></span>some link<span class="close"></span></a>
</p>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @hungerstar - why do you hate jsfiddle? :-) just kidding

Comment: @Jamesonthedog a lot of the times (like this question) there really is no reason for someone to leave the site to see a viable example. The example is very straight forward and basic. What if JSFiddle goes away in 6 months? All those links are no good. With a Stack Snippet future users that find this question valuable won't be hung out to dry as everything is contained/available on SO. **P.S.** I love JSFiddle, I use it all the time to quick test something out or creating basic demos. For SO though I try to use/encourage Stack Snippets.

Comment: you, my friend, are a true champion of the community - I applaud you (and I truly mean it) @hungerstar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `background-position-y: 2px;` and add `vertical-align:middle;` to your `a span`.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
a span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 13px;
}
a .open {
  background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_161877bracketleft.gif');
}
a .close {
  background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_762032bracketright.gif');
}
```

```html
<p>
  some text <a href="#"><span class="open"></span>some link<span class="close"></span></a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to dump your way of doing it with 2 spans and do it with only 1 instead.

```css
.state::before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 5px;
   height: 15px;
   background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_161877bracketleft.gif');
}
.state::after{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 5px;
   height: 15px;
   background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_762032bracketright.gif');
}
```

```html
<p>
   some text <a href="#"><span class="state">some link</span></a>
</p>
```

You should make some adjustments according to your needs, but that's the basics.

Comment: Why not 0 `<span>` and use pseudo elements on the `<a>` itself?

Comment: @hungerstar Yeah, good one. I missed that in the hurry. Also, there are some contradictions with the current css of the author and some margins need to be added to look good. Otherwise it seems fine.

Comment: Hi, yes I know I can do it with 1 or 0 span element. I just forget to specify that I can't use pseudo-element like :before or :after. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align:middle` with `a .open` and `a .close`.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
a span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 13px;
}
a .open {
  background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_161877bracketleft.gif');
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a .close {
  background-image: url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_762032bracketright.gif');
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  some text <a href="#"><span class="open"></span>some link<span class="close"></span></a>
</p>
```